# How to add vias and more traces?

Tags: eaglecad, wire, via, error

[image]

I am getting a Drill Size error and overlapping errors because I added a new via and a wire to my PCB. I'm not really sure why I am getting these errors. Is there a way to add a new wire and get it to connect to a wire that was already there without getting an overlap error? Also, do I need to make that via bigger in size? If so, how? I attached a picture that shows the area I need help with.

Comment: You need to make sure the net of the new via/wire match the net of the old via/wire. Also, that layout is horrific! What a mess! Stick to 45 degree traces, and get rid of that stupid "staircase" track. It's completely ridiculous. Also avoid acute angles.

Comment: How do I change the net of the new via/old via?

Comment: Use the "name" tool

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the "Name" tool to change the name of the new via and net to match that of the old one (that you are trying to connect to). Once the nets have the same name, Eagle should allow you to connect them together without complaining about overlapping.

Comment: I did that and they all have the same name now. The overlapping errors went away. I still am having problems with the drill size error.

Comment: Well of course you are, that's a completely different error. Somewhere in your rules you telling Eagle that you need to have a minimum drill size, and the hole in that via it's pointing to is smaller than this minimum. Therefore, it is throwing an error. To fix it you need to either update your rules (and make sure you note the capabilities of your board house), or increase the hole size in the via.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eagle light version 6.5.0 Linux.

Having the exact same problem, I tried (almost) everything and nothing helps.

After 3 days I finally found the answer:

Click on I (top left button) and click (twice) on the via to display properties.

I got inner layer and outer layer diameter being 0.04 for a correct via and 0.039... something for a bad one.
Also the correct drill is 0.024 versus 0.023... something.
I adjusted these 3 settings in this properties screen and voila, the problem disappeared.

I hope I can help someone with this story.