# Drill Size Error in Eagle Cad

Tags: eaglecad, error, cad

[image]

No matter what I do, I still have these errors. I don't know what to do to fix this. Please help!!

Comment: Should I change the DRC rules??

Comment: Firstly, could you give us more information? What things did you try, list them. Secondly, I suspect you simply use a thing that needs a very small drill; yet you set the relevant parameter in the design rule check to a larger size. Check with your fab-house what the design constraints (i.e. minimum drill diameter in this case) are, many do even provide a file specifically for eagle.

Comment: @LindaCamm -- you should change the DRC rules if your fab-house has the capabilities you require. Otherwise its the design you need to change... Check your vias, its quite likely they are the smallest holes you used on the PCB. As a reference, 0.3mm is a very reasonable hole that most fab houses can make (leading to about 0.2mm via after plating)

Comment: @LindaCamm I already answered this question here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/251312/41856 . **DO NOT** start a new question on the **SAME TOPIC** you already asked (and got answers for)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you zoom in on your layout, and then double click on any of those violations, it will take you directly to the section of the board where the violation is highlighted, in case you didn't already know that. Either the holes *have* to be that size and you need to find a manufacturer that supports that drill size, and change your DRCs accordingly, or you need to change the size of the holes to be compliant with the capabilities of your manufacturer.

Here is a screen shot of the DRC section that is relevant to your error.
[image]

Comment: @LindaCamm if it solved the problem, click the tick mark next to the vote in the top left of the answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

The drill size error is most likely showing up because it is set to a larger size in the design rules section. Try decreasing it and see if that helps.

For example: you can't drill a 2mm hole with a 20mm bit. I've had this issue with Eagle before and it helped to revise the DRC